# In generative grammar, is the first auxiliary always the head of an interrogative clause?

Tags: generative-grammar, phrase-structure, auxiliary-verbs

In generative grammar, be it transformational or not, is the first auxiliary always the head of an interrogative clause? For example, in (1), is the first auxiliary *will* always the head of (1)?

> (1) ***Will** you have finished it by tomorrow?*

Since in dependency grammar it's always the head, I'd like to know whether there's any branch of phrase structure grammar in which it can not be the head.

Answer (score 1):

Not always. In the Aspects model, there is no concept "head". In Burt's exposition, the auxiliary is moved into a node PreS which is a sister to the NP, Aux and VP.

Comment: Is there a branch of phrase structure grammar in which the first auxiliary _will_ is the head of declarative clause _I will have finished it by tomorrow_ but is not the head of interrogative clause _Will you have finished it by tomorrow?_?

Comment: In McCawley's syntax, there's no syntactic concept of "head", either.

Comment: The "Aspects model" does not elaborate the concept of a head, but I don't think it claims human language is exocentric. _Aspects of the Theory of Syntax_ mentions "head" a couple times: e.g., "the selectional features must involve the
lexical categories that are the heads of grammatically related
phrases..." The book mentions the term "Complement" numerous times. Were it not an endocentric model, why would "Complement" be mentioned so many times? Moreover, Chomsky developed X-bar theory, which is centered around the concept of "head", based on, rather than rejecting, the Aspects model.

Comment: So I don't know why you would argue that in the Aspects model, there is no concept "head". So please elaborate. Also, I don't know who Burt is.

Comment: @jlawler Are you sure? _The Syntactic Phenomena of English_ clearly embraces the concept of 'head'. Page 216, for example, has this: _Given that the various auxiliary verbs are verbs in virtue of their being inflected like verbs (albeit with a highly defective paradigm, in the case of modal auxiliaries), the most obvious way for them to fit into constituent structure is as the head of a V', so that sentences with multiple auxiliaries would have a surface structure as in (4), with nested V's:_

Comment: In that particular paragraph, he simply meant the "main verb" of  a V', which is part of his own system of projection (not Chomskyan X-bars). There is no definition of "head" as a syntactic property that must be preserved under transformation. So the answer to your title question is "It is if you want to call it that".

Comment: @jlawler _There is no definition of "head" as a syntactic property that must be preserved under transformation._ Is this about transformation in general or McCawley's transformation in particular?

Comment: McCawley's syntax does not use _head_ as a technical term (like _noun_ or _constituent_) with tests and definitions.

Comment: @jlawler _The Syntactic Phenomena of English_  (p13) says: _In virtue of the fact that the syntactic behavior of a phrasal unit depends on the part of speech of its **head** (the word on which the other parts of the unit are dependent), categories of the second sort are given names in which the symbol for the part of speech of the head is combined with a symbol (the prime) indicating "phrasal unit." V' means "phrasal unit whose head is a V"; thus, a unit consisting of a verb plus whatever objects or complements it may have is a V'._ So "head" is a technical term used throughout the book.

Comment: @jlawler Moreover, The book's index at the end shows that the term "head" was used throughout the book: **Head, 13, 15, 189, 206-9, 756-60, 767-69** Although he doesn't adopt X bar theory as presented by Chomsky, McCawley's syntactic theory is very similar to X bar theory in that it views human language as endocentric.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I'm corrected.